# Sum the value in if/else mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Not sure how to MAX the date inside if/else statement of MySQL query.

Here my select statement:

```
SELECT MONTH(Max(a.planned_date))                     AS MONTH, 
       a.planned_date                                 AS DATE, 
       YEAR(Max(a.planned_date))                      AS YEAR, 
       Sum(IF(MONTH(a.planned_date) = 1, b.VALUE, 0)) AS Jan, 
       Sum(IF(MONTH(a.planned_date) = 2, b.VALUE, 0)) AS Feb, 
       Sum(b.VALUE)                                   AS total 
FROM   b 
       INNER JOIN a 
               ON b.id = a.id 
       INNER JOIN c 
               ON b.reg_id = c.reg_id 
WHERE  YEAR(a.planned_date) < DATE(Now()) 
GROUP  BY c.reg_id
```

All I am trying to do is to have a cross table of Jan to Dec, but return a MAX date to bring the value. However, the way I have done it the value is doubling up the value.

Please help your advise is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Post a sample data and the table schema

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query